# how can i define a cookie global?

Tags: php, cookies

i defined a cookie in a page like check.php and set it.

```
setcookie("u","blue",time() + 3600);
```

now i want to check that if it is set or no in another page like index.php.

i sure that cookie is set in check.php but when i check that in index.php with this code:

```
if( isset($_COOKIE["u"] ) )
  {
        echo "correct";
  }
```

it doesn't worked!!and if doesn't run?
what is problem?if cookies worked only in that page that it defined?

Edit:

i change it to `setcookie("u","blue",time() + 3600,'/', 'www.example.vcn.ir');`
but has same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update:

Set the domain to NULL or FALSE as your working on localhost.

Try setting the cookie path and domain.

```
setcookie ("u", 'blue', time()+3600, '/', NULL, 0 );
```

Try var_dumping $_COOKIE to see whats in it..

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Comment: i run it on **xammp** now what i wrote instead www.example.com?

Comment: setcookie("u","blue",time() + 3600,'/', 'localhost'); but it's output is array(0)

Comment: i realized it.the correct answer was **setcookie("user", "blue", false, "/", false);** your answer was useful too.thanks